# Storage of a Spare Mezuzah Scroll

Tags: mezuzah

What is the best way to store an additional Mezuzah scroll?  Somehow "in a drawer" seems wrong, but hanging it on a wall also seems wrong.

Unfortunately, I have need for a spare due to harsh winters where I live.  I am obliged to check my scrolls more often because of ice covering the Mezuzah on one door.

Comment: Is this a halachic question or a best practice for effective storage question. Please edit to clarify

Comment: If you are asking a halachic question, please also clarify your claim that storing it in a drawer is wrong. Where do you think scribes store their spare mezuzah scrolls (e.g., the ones that they haven't sold, yet)?

Comment: Somehow "in a drawer" seems wrong. Not at all. Of course don't leave them I'm the drawer with the kid's crayons.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest keeping your spare mezuzah scrolls in a [Vaultz storage box](http://www.vaultz.net/). They should keep the scrolls nice and protected, because they both lock and have a cloth-like inside lining.

This [sunglasses box](http://www.vaultz.net/catalog/boxes-cases/sunglass-cases/locking-sport-sunglass-case-tactical-black-vaultz-vz03632.html) might fit your needs. My favorite box they sell though is actually a [vaping supply box](http://www.vaultz.net/catalog/boxes-cases/vaporvaultz-reg/vaultz-vz00498-black-small-locking-vaporvaultz-case.html) (without the [vaping supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_cigarette), of course).